# Dates calculations in DatePicker

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker

I am trying to get some values using DatePicker.

Here is the Jsfiddle that I am working on. I managed to get it work for initial stage but I need more help.

http://jsfiddle.net/vdpzzms2/2/

```
/** Days to be disabled as an array */
var disabledSpecificDays = ["12-25-2014", "12-31-2014"];



function disableSpecificDaysAndWeekends(date) {
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var y = date.getFullYear();



    for (var i = 0; i < disabledSpecificDays.length; i++) {
        if ($.inArray((m + 1) + '-' + d + '-' + y, disabledSpecificDays) != -1 || new Date() > date) {
            return [false];
        }
    }

    var noWeekend = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
    return !noWeekend[0] ? noWeekend : [true];

}


/** init datepicker */
$(document).ready(function () {

   $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val();

    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: disableSpecificDaysAndWeekends
    });




});
```

1. Could the date to be in "DD, d MM, yy" format
2. Could the default date show-up in the Current Date field when the textbox loads (before I select the date)
3. Would like to calculate Shipping and Delivery Dates

Answer (score 1):

I think i have solved all three issues of yours

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/j8r622bf/1/)

```
/** Days to be disabled as an array */
var disabledSpecificDays = ["12-25-2014", "12-31-2014"];

function disableSpecificDaysAndWeekends(date) {
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    for (var i = 0; i < disabledSpecificDays.length; i++) {
        if ($.inArray((m + 1) + '-' + d + '-' + y, disabledSpecificDays) != -1 || new Date() > date) {
            return [false];
        }
    }

    var noWeekend = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
    return !noWeekend[0] ? noWeekend : [true];
}

function calc(dateInText){
    var dateObj = new Date(dateInText);
    var tmrw = new Date(dateInText);
    var shipD = 0;
    while(shipD != 5){
        tmrw.setDate(tmrw.getDate() + 1);
        if(disableSpecificDaysAndWeekends(tmrw)[0]){
            shipD++;
        }
    }
    $('#ShippingDate').val($.datepicker.formatDate('DD, d MM, yy',tmrw));
    var delD = 0;
    while(delD != 6){
        dateObj.setDate(dateObj.getDate() + 1);
        if(disableSpecificDaysAndWeekends(dateObj)[0]){
            delD++;
        }
    }
    $('#DeliveryDate').val($.datepicker.formatDate('DD, d MM, yy',dateObj));
}

/** init datepicker */
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $now = new Date();
    $now.setDate($now.getDate() + 1);
    $('#datepicker').val($.datepicker.formatDate('DD, d MM, yy',$now)).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'DD, d MM, yy',
        beforeShowDay: disableSpecificDaysAndWeekends,
        onClose : calc
    });
    calc($now);
});
```

**UPDATE**

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/j8r622bf/6/) updated code

Comment: Thanks a lot @Cerlin. This code is out of my mind. Cerlin I have made few changes to explanation of text boxes. Can you please check it when you find time and fine-tune it? http://jsfiddle.net/iamkrishnam/j8r622bf/4/

Comment: fine tune what? i am not sure on what you are asking. (i think the functionality is working as it should. Please test the functionality and give feedback)

Comment: First of all, I thank you from the bottom of my heart. Your code is just perfect and I am not saying anything regarding that. I just made my explanations much better and increased font size so that the text is clear for reading. Thank you for taking time and getting back to me.

Comment: I need one more feature - Can we display the date as next day incase the time is more than 12NOON? For example — If Today's Date is Wednesday, 17 December 2014 and time is Greater than 12NOON (time format 24 hours) then one extra day should be added to Today's Date and hence should be treated as Thursday, 18 December 2014 and the rest of the calculations should be based on this . Please help when you find time.   http://jsfiddle.net/iamkrishnam/ebezs3Lf/

Comment: time is selected(using some plugin) or typed?

Comment: The time is not typed. It's taken from the system. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Cerlin. I need small change. The date in the Today's Date shows today's date and the Current Time loads the current time. Only while calculating the Shipping Date increased by 1 day if the current time is more than 12Noon. Please update when you find time. Thanks a lot!

Comment: are you talking about this update? http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/j8r622bf/6/ At the moment Today's Date shows the Next Day date even if the time is NOT more than 12noon. Can we display the Current Time (Hours, Mins, seconds) in the text box?

Comment: try inputting current time 11 and then try 12. the date will automatically change

Comment: I just checked in @Cerlin and there is no change. Can we do like this? Let Today's Date show Today's Date without any change but while calculating Shipping and Delivery we can consider the time as mentioned above. Please advise.

Comment: sry i am not sure what your expected output is.

Comment: Sorry @Cerlin for the confusion. Can we please display Today's Date as it is? ----- And when someone selects the date and then if the current time is more than 12AM ONLY then it adds ONE EXTRA DAY to [(Shipping Date = Today's Date + 4 Days [excluding Weekends and Disabled Days]) and ONE EXTRA DAY to (Delivery Date = Shipping Date + 1 Day [excluding Weekends and Disabled Days]). Hope I could explain it better.

Comment: For example: If I select Today's Date = Thursday, 18 Dec 2014 and if the time is less than or equal to 12AM then the Shipping Date and Deliver Date work as it is without any change. But if I select Today's Date = Thursday, 18 Dec 2014 and if the time is greater than 12AM then ONE EXTRA DAY is added to Shipping Date and Delivery Date WITH ALREADY EXISTING CALCULATIONS. Hope I could explain this better. Please let me know if you didn't follow.

Comment: but the datepicker doesnt have an option to select todays date.

Comment: By default the user can select Today's Date as well. From Today user can select any Date. Please enable it.

Answer (score 0):

Your first two questions are quite straight-forward but I'm unsure of the date format you want, an example would help but to change it, just change the string for the default value and the `dateFormat` option in the `datepicker` initialisation.

I know it's an external library but [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) is excellent for messing around with dates, durations and formatting.

Your third question is quite complicated and should probably be its own question on SO.

One thing to note is that your `datepicker` seems to only allow dates from tomorrow and I am populating the initial value with today's date so it's disabled, not sure if you want the initial value to be tomorrow or to allow today to be selected, I can't see where today is disabled though.

```
/** Days to be disabled as an array */
var disabledSpecificDays = ["12-25-2014", "12-31-2014"];

function disableSpecificDaysAndWeekends(date) {
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    for (var i = 0; i < disabledSpecificDays.length; i++) {
        if ($.inArray((m + 1) + '-' + d + '-' + y, disabledSpecificDays) != -1 || new Date() > date) {
            return [false];
        }
    }

    var noWeekend = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
    return !noWeekend[0] ? noWeekend : [true];

}


/** init datepicker */
$(document).ready(function () {

    // get today's date and format it
    var today = new Date();
    // zero pad the date and month incase they are less than 10
    var dd = ("0" + today.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var mm = ("0" + (today.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2); // January is 0!
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();


    var day_names = [
        'Sunday',
        'Monday',
        'Tuesday',
        'Wednesday',
        'Thursday',
        'Friday',
        'Saturday'
    ];

    var month_names = [
        'January',
        'February',
        'March',
        'April',
        'May',
        'June',
        'July',
        'August',
        'September',
        'October',
        'November',
        'December'
    ];

   var day_name = day_names[today.getDay()];
   var month_name = month_names[today.getMonth()];

   $('#datepicker').val(day_name + ', ' + dd + ' ' + month_name + ', ' + yyyy);

   $('#datepicker').datepicker({ 
       dateFormat: 'DD, d MM, yy',
       beforeShowDay: disableSpecificDaysAndWeekends
   });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vdpzzms2/3/

**Update**

This is a bit messy and could be done better via an intermediate function that takes care of the logic or by using an external library but here you go (doesn't take weekends or disabled dates into consideration):

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ 
   dateFormat: 'DD, d MM, yy',
   beforeShowDay: disableSpecificDaysAndWeekends,
   onSelect: function(date) {
       // alert(date);
       var selected_date = new Date(date);
       var shipping_date = new Date(date);
       shipping_date.setDate(shipping_date.getDate() + 4);
       var delivery_date = new Date(date)
       delivery_date.setDate(delivery_date.getDate() + 5);

       var shipping_dd = ("0" + shipping_date.getDate()).slice(-2);
       var shipping_mm = ("0" + (shipping_date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2); //January is 0!
       var shipping_yyyy = shipping_date.getFullYear();
       var shipping_day_name = day_names[shipping_date.getDay()];
       var shipping_month_name = month_names[shipping_date.getMonth()];

       var formatted_shipping_date = shipping_day_name + ', ' + shipping_dd + ' ' + shipping_month_name + ', ' + shipping_yyyy;

       var delivery_dd = ("0" + delivery_date.getDate()).slice(-2);
       var delivery_mm = ("0" + (delivery_date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2); //January is 0!
       var delivery_yyyy = delivery_date.getFullYear();
       var delivery_day_name = day_names[delivery_date.getDay()];
       var delivery_month_name = month_names[delivery_date.getMonth()];

       var formatted_delivery_date = delivery_day_name + ', ' + delivery_dd + ' ' + delivery_month_name + ', ' + delivery_yyyy;

       $('#ShippingDate').val(formatted_shipping_date);
       $('#DeliveryDate').val(formatted_delivery_date);

   }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vdpzzms2/7/

Comment: Thanks Martin. I've formatted the code so that it's clear now. Here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/vdpzzms2/4/ Martin, I want to get Today's Date in a variable TodayDate and then Add 3 days to it and then display it in the Text Box named Shipping Date and same in Delivery Date with addition of 4 Days. Please help.